# Wordpress Database Connection Error Using Docker-compose

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

Im using docker-compose to spin up a mysql and a Wordpress container. Im greeted with an connection / authentication error when accessing the site. I can't find the reason why ?! (I have also tried using root user.)

Below is my compose file, part of config file, and the error.

[image]

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - './database:/var/lib/mysql'
      - './config/database_dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/database_dump.sql'
  wp:
    image: wordpress:latest
    container_name: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '7777:80'
    volumes:
      - './wordpress:/var/www/html'
      - './config/wp-config.php:/var/www/html/wp-config.php'
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

**wp-config.php**

```
define('DB_NAME', 'my_db_name');
define('DB_USER', 'user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_HOST', 'mysql:3306');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect you inside your mysql container with `docker exec -it mysqlxxxxx /bin/bash` connect to mysql with `mysql -proot` and after create your database `create database my_db_name`

Comment: Responded with: ERROR 1007 (HY000): Can't create database 'my_db_name'; database exists

Comment: and when you're inside the wp container, the wp-config.php file is correct?

Comment: I have switched to using root user. The same error occurs.

Comment: the php file is correctly inserted into the wp container